# General function that adds segments to a graph in quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to write a simple function in the format of `add_TA` that adds general segments to a plot. 
The function will receive an N by 4 matrix. Each row in the matrix is a segment.

I'v tried modifying `add_SMA` to my needs but no luck.

```
add_Segments <- function (segs , ...) 
{
    lenv <- new.env()
    lenv$add_segments <- function(segs , ...) {
        segments(segs[,1] , segs[,2] , segs[,3] , segs[,4] , ...)
    }
    mapply(function(name, value) {
        assign(name, value, envir = lenv)
    }, names(list(segs = segs , ...)), list(segs = segs, ...))  
    plot_object <- current.chob()
    lenv$xdata <- segs
    plot_object$set_frame(2)
    exp <- parse(text = "add_segments(segs = segs , ...)")
    plot_object$add(exp, env = c(lenv, plot_object$Env), expr = TRUE)
    plot_object
}
```

This fails with

```
Error in plot.window(c(1, 1658), c(NaN, NaN)) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

I though I toke care of that when I set `xdata` in `lenv` but I guess I didn't.

This is a reproducible example that illustrates the result and that `segments` work properly.

```
require(quantmod)
s <- get(getSymbols('MSFT'))["2012"]
chart_Series(s)
segs <- matrix(c(183,31.61,213,30.20,221,26.34,233,26.26) , byrow = T , nrow = 2)
segments(segs[,1] , segs[,2] , segs[,3] , segs[,4] , col = 'red')
```

The reason i'm using the `add_TA` format (and not just drawing as in the sample above) is that I want to add additional indicators and I want the segments to stay on the graph after  plot object refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `add_Series` function, but you have to do a little more manipulation to get the data in the right format.  The function below does those manipulations for you.

```
interp <- function(Data, Points) {
  # merge points with original data to create NA
  m <- merge(Data[Points], index(Data))
  # linear approximation at equidistant spacing,
  # rather than at index values (the default)
  na.approx(m, seq(nrow(Data)))
}

chart_Series(s)
add_Series(interp(Hi(s), c(183,213)), type="line", on=1)
add_Series(interp(Lo(s), c(221,233)), type="line", on=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua. Thats Great. One thing though - I couldn't make it work with `add_Series` nor with `add_TA(.. , type=  'l')`. the only way the line is drawn on the plot is when I use `add_TA(x , type = 'p')`. You have any idea why is that ?

Comment: Hey @Joshua , I just tested the function with 43 lines over a daily time series from 2007-2013. It took +30 Seconds to complete. I'm guessing the merge and the approximation takes up a lot of time. since they are unnecessary in this case, we are using them to be able to use the existing interface, Can you maybe think of a way of making it work with segments rather then series ?

Comment: @haki: what do you mean you "couldn't make it work"? It works for me. The reason 43 lines takes so long is probably because you're calling the functions like I do in my answer, which causes the plot to be re-drawn after every function call. Put all the `add_Series` calls in the `TA=` argument of `chart_Series`. E.g., `chart_Series(s, TA="add_Series(...);add_Series(...);...")`.